# PyQt4: Move items from one QListWidget to another

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I created an interface on Qt Designer and am using it in a QGIS plugin.  The interface consists of a source `listWidget`, a destination `listWidget`, and  `pushButton`.

I am trying to bring selected items over from the source `listWidget` to the destination `listWidget`.

I populated by my source `listWidget` using:

```
self.ui.listWidget_1.addItems(soilList)
```

And so far I have written my button signal as:

```
QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.click_pushButton)
```

But now I am having trouble writing the `click_pushButton` function that populates the destination `listWidget`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`QListWidget.selectedIndexes()` will return a list of indexes for selected items. Where each index has a `.row()` method returning the row of the item. Then you can use `.takeItem()` to get (and remove) the item from the first list, and add it to the second list via `.addItem()`.

That translates to:

```
def click_pushButton(self):
    # sort rows in descending order in order to compensate shifting due to takeItem
    rows = sorted([index.row() for index in self.ui.listWidget_1.selectedIndexes()],
                  reverse=True)
    for row in rows:
        # assuming the other listWidget is called listWidget_2
        self.ui.listWidget_2.addItem(self.ui.listWidget_1.takeItem(row))

# moving all items:
def click_pushButton(self):
    for row in reversed(range(self.ui.listWidget_1.count()):
        # assuming the other listWidget is called listWidget_2
        self.ui.listWidget_2.addItem(self.ui.listWidget_1.takeItem(row))
```

By the way, please give your widgets/methods meaningful names. `listWidget_1` or `click_pushButton` says nothing about what these stand for.

And use [new style signals and slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). You can write that connect statement like this:

```
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_pushButton)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I also tried to write a code that moves all the items in the ListWidget at once with:  
                                                                   def move_all_items_todestination(self):
 for index in range(len(self.ui.sourceList)):
   self.ui.destinationList.addItem(self.ui.sourceList.takeItem(index))

But when I execute the pushButton, it only moves half of the items in my source listWidget to my destination listWidget instead of all of them.  Any ideas of why it does that?

Comment: @user1270516: Ouch! :). `.takeItem` removes the thing so indexes are shifted. You need to start from the largest index. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A QListwidgetitem can only exist in one QListwidget unless cloned.

Here is a straightforward PyQt5 solution which avoids the bookkeeping of indices:

```
self.ui.clone_items_button.clicked.connect(self.clone_selected_listwidgetitems)

def clone_selected_listwidgetitems(self)
    for sel_item in self.ui.source_listwidget.selectedItems():
        cloned_item = sel_item.clone()
        self.ui.destination_listwidget.addItem(cloned_item)
```